# Extent Reports in Cucumber throwing an error

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Hi below is my runner class file

```
package Runners;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(           strict=true
                            ,features={"C:\\Users\\Narendra\\workspace\\Grab_On\\Features\\Bank_Filter.feature"},

                            plugin={"pretty:STDOUT","C:\\Users\\Narendra\\workspace\\Grab_On\\Reports\\Cucumber-pretty",
                                    "json:C:\\Users\\Narendra\\workspace\\Grab_On\\Reports\\Cucumber-json",
                                    "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormater:C:\\Users\\Narendra\\workspace\\Grab_On\\Reports\\Cucumber-extent\\report.html"
                                    },
                            glue = {"Scripts"}
                            ,dryRun=false


                    )
public class Bank_Filter_Runner {

    @AfterClass
    public static void reportsetup()
    {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src/test/java/Resources/extent-config.xml"));
        Properties p=System.getProperties();
        p.list(System.out);
        /*
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("User.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("User.timezone"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("64 Bit", "Windows 7");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("2.53.0", "Selenium");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("3.5.0", "Maven");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("1.8.0_151", "Java Version");
        Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Cucumber JUnit Test Runner");
        */
    }


}
```

while i am executing it i am getting an error saying that as below:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: C

can some one help me on this please..

Comment: ExtentCucumberFormater Should it be ExtentCucumberFormatter?

Comment: Correct the spelling for Formatter like below : plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:yourpath/report.html"},
Nice example of Extent Report in Cucumber framework is given here:
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/cucumber-extent-report/

Comment: @LakshaySharma that works thanks a lot for your time and helping me